# Pandas: Filter each client by different date

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I have transactions of different customers.

```
Customer | Ticket |     Date    | StartDate
   A         000     08-12-2017   01-01-2018
   B         001     17-12-2017   01-01-2018
   A         002     05-01-2018   01-01-2018
   A         003     05-01-2018   01-01-2018
   B         004     17-02-2018   01-01-2018
```

StartDate is when each customer started using the app. So, I have transactions of customer frmo before they started using the app. Each customer have different StartDate. How can I filter the transactions and get only the transactions after each customer started using the app.

In this example I will only get the ticket 002, 003 and 004 since ticket 000 and 001 are from ebfore each customer started using the app.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `query` method:

```
df.query('Date > StartDate')
```

Or boolean indexing:

```
df[df['Date'] > df['StartDate']]
```

Output:

```
  Customer  Ticket       Date  StartDate
2        A       2 2018-05-01 2018-01-01
3        A       3 2018-05-01 2018-01-01
4        B       4 2018-02-17 2018-01-01
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure Data and StartDate are stored as date:

   ```
   df.info()
   ```

if not date:

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format="%d-%m-%Y")
df.StartDate = pd.to_datetime(df.StartDate, format="%d-%m-%Y")
```

2: compare columns:

```
df2 = df[df.StartDate < df.Date]
```

That should do it